# why there is difference when build static lib and dynamic lib in solaris11.3 on x86?

Tags: c++, c++11, solaris

I am using solaris 11.3 on x86, using gcc 4.8.2. I want to compile two types of library files: dynamic library and static library  for the same code.  First I compiled the dynamic library and test in app, It works ok.  But when I compiled the static library (test in app), it works not ok. There is link error, like:

```
Undefined                        first referenced
 symbol                             in file
std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_next_bkt(unsigned int) const    in xxxx file 
std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const   in xxxx file 
std::_Hash_bytes(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)   in xxxx file  
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)   in xxxx file
```

I using the strings command  to look up to undefined symbol. In first I check the libstdc++.so, there is no no information to related symbols. In the dynamic lib (libxxx.so) there is no references to related symbols. In the static lib (libxxx.a), there is indeed references to related symbols. Just like:

```
## strings libxxx.so | grep _M_widen_init
nothing to export 
## strings libxxx.a | grep _M_widen_init
```

the export is like:

```
_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initE
```

Why the static lib contents undefined symbols? How should I adjust the compile and link options to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643738/elf-linking-why-do-i-get-undefined-references-in-so-files may help.

Comment: Post your full compile commands for both the static and the dynamic libraries, along with the commands used to link both static and dynamic versions of your application.  You're likely missing a dependency somehow.